# populateView is called multiple times

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

`populateView` method of the `FirebaseListAdapter` class runs twice as often than expected and I don't know why. Here I put the database Firebase:

[image: BBdd]

This is the class that handles the data model

```
public class Chat {

String name;
String text;
String uid;

public Chat() {
}

public Chat(String name, String uid, String message) {
    this.name = name;
    this.text = message;
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}
```

And this is the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
FirebaseListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView messagesView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messages_list);

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Chat>(this, Chat.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, ref) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, Chat chatMessage, int position) {
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(chatMessage.getName());
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(chatMessage.getText());

        }
    };
    messagesView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Did your `messagesView` get result like this `item1, item1, item2, item2, item3, item3` or `item1, item2, item3, item1, item2, item3`?